# Updating specific value in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm just starting my adventure with Ruby, and I have a problem. I've completed Codecademy's Ruby course, so I'm not THAT green, but i still don't know too much. Anyway. How can you update a specific value with an equation? Like, here is what I'm trying to do with the following hash:

```
hash = { "s1" => 2, "s2" => 3 }
```

What I want to do next, is get input via `gets.chomp` to get the key, and then acquire the amount to add to `value` (via `gets.chomp` as well). Here's what I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
name = gets.chomp
value = gets.chomp.to_i
hash.each do |x, y|
  if x == name
    y == y + value
  else
    puts "nope"
  end
end
```

I have also tried messing around with `Hash#update` but with no luck.
Can anyone help please? I've been stuck on it for like 3 hours already :/

Cheers, 
Boberczus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a block, both `x` and `y` are local variables, updating them makes no effect. You might `map` instead:

```
hash.map do |x, y|
  [x, if x == name
        y + value
      else
        puts "nope"
        y
      end
  ]
end.to_h
```

But the easiest way would be:

```
if hash[name]
  hash[name] += value
else
  puts "nope"
end
```

Using update:

```
hash.update({name => value})
```

Comment: Hah! Thank you! Now I can move on. I was totally overcomplicating things.  Gotta read documentation more carefully. Cheers.